# Explanation of implementation of an algorithm for Dominating Set

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I'm working on an application, in which users can use domination in graphs. I have already finished up with graph generation algorithm, I use lists to store vertices...
So, I have found a well [developed, gorgeous implementation](https://github.com/drange/Grapher/blob/master/src/no/uib/ii/algo/st8/algorithms/ExactDominatingSet.java) of the needed algorithm.

It is a bit complicated for me, I would like to ask for some description for code above. How is it working? I would like to get only a short summary.

Comment: Your question seems to be about how to read somebody else's code. If that's the case, it's not on-topic, here. I'm not sure where it would be on-topic within the Stack Exchange network. [so], [codereview.se] and [programmers.se] are the obvious places to look but I don't think it really fits any of them.

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm just tries every subset of the vertices and calculates whether it is a dominating set.  It tries the subsets in increasing order of size, and halts whenever it finds one.

Note that the running time is $O(2^n n)$ so it is exponential, and quite badly so.  There are faster algorithms that compute dominating sets in $O^*(1.7^n)$ or even $O^*(1.5^n)$ time, but I don't recall whether they are implementable.

By the way, dominating set, being W[2]-complete, is not expected to have an algorithm running in time $f(k) \cdot \text{poly}(n)$ for any function $f$ where $k$ is the size of a minimum dominating set.

Comment: "whether they are implementable" -- what does that mean here? Every algorithm is implementable (disregarding such that use super-Turing oracles). Do you mean if they are worth impementing (because of galactic hidden constants) or easy to implement (because of absurd code complexity)?